# Is the higher direct image sheaf of a locally free sheaf over $\mathbb{P}^1$ locally free?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, sheaf-cohomology

Let $f:X \to \mathbb{P}^1$ be a projective flat morphism, $X$ is a projective scheme. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a locally free sheaf on $X$. Are the higher direct image sheaves $R^if_*\mathcal{F}$ locally free for all $i>0$?

Comment: What are the assumptions on $X$? Is it a scheme or what?

Comment: You stipulate that $i > 0$. Do you know a counter-example when $i=0$?

Comment: You might find it useful to read about the geometry/topology of "Lefschetz fibrations".

Comment: Can you tell us more about your sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ and your map $f$?  For many sheaves related to differentials (twisted in various "nice" ways) assuming $f$ is nice enough, the statement is true.

Comment: @Schwede: Could you give some example or reference. In my case $\mathcal{F}$ is the normal sheaf of $X$.

Comment: @Jana (Normal sheaf of $X$ embedded where).  Anyway, there are a number of references.  For instance if the family has Du Bois fibers, you could see Section 7 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/0902.0648.pdf

Comment: @Schwede: $X$ is a projective scheme. Suppose $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$. Then, $\mathcal{F}:=\mathcal{N}_{X|\mathbb{P}^n}$

Comment: @Jana I see, I didn't realize you had fixed an embedding into $\mathbb{P}^n$.  You should also see many papers of Kollar on torsion-freeness of higher direct images of various sheaves.  I assume since you accepted the answer below, you don't have much control on the singularities of the fibers?

Comment: @Schwede: The example that I was considering in that case the fibers of $f$ were locally complete intersection curves in $\mathbb{P}^3$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. For instance there is a flat, projective morphism $f:X\rightarrow \Bbb{P}^1$ such that $X_t:=f^{-1}(t)$ is a smooth rational curve for $t\neq 0$, but $X_0$ is a nodal plane cubic curve with an embedded point (see Hartshorne, III.9.8.4).  Then $H^1(X_t,\mathcal{O}_{X_t})$ is zero for $t\neq 0$, but $\ \dim H^1(X_0,\mathcal{O}_{X_0})=1$ . By base change it follows that $R^1f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is the skyscraper sheaf with 1-dimensional fiber at 0.

Comment: I am a bit confused right now. I noticed in the example that you state $X_0$ is not a closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^2$. So I do not totally understand why $f$ is projective. Adding to my confusion is the corollary $7.8.7$ in EGA-III which if I understand correctly means that the dimension of the global sections of the structure sheaf remains contant in this example if it were projective. Could you tell me what is it that I am getting wrong?

Comment: Projectivity is not a problem, look at Hartshorne, example 9.8.4. And for your EGA corollary, the key hypothesis, namely that $H^0(X_0,\mathcal{O}_{X_0})$ is a separable $\mathbb{C}$-algebra (i.e. $\mathbb{C}\times \ldots \times \mathbb{C}$) is not satisfied.

Comment: The last line of the example says it is not a closed subscheme (see last line on pp. 259). Isnt $H^0(\mathcal{O}_{X_0})$ a finite dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-vector space?

Comment: It is of course, but not a separable algebra.